# Pivot Table from recordset in VB6

Tags: excel, vb6

I have a pivot table in an Excel file that I'm looking to use with data from a recordset.  So far, this is what I have

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlptCache As Excel.PivotCache
Dim xlptTable As Excel.PivotTable
Dim pivotRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset
'Open Excel File and set data for pivotRecordSet

With xlWbook
    Set xlWSheet = .Worksheets("Sheet1")        
    Set xlptCache = .PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal)
    'Trying this gives me an Application-defined or object-defined error
    'Set .PivotCaches.item(0).Recordset = pivotRecordSet
End With
'I also tried this with the same error when setting the recordset
Set xlptTable = xlWSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set xlptTable.PivotCache.Recordset = pivotRecordSet
```

I know I can create a new pivot table with this

```
 Set xlptTable = 
 xlWSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=xlptCache,   
 TableDestination:=xlWSheet.Range("D4"),tablename:="PT_Report")
```

is there any way I can alter that to use an existing pivot table rather than creating a new one?  Or am I doing something wrong with changing the recordset that is causing the error?

Comment: I can't see the code for data being pulled into the recordset. From where is the recordset being filled with the actual data?

Comment: I'm filling it with data from a SQL Server DB.  I'm looping through one ADODB.Recordset into the pivotRecordSet.  If I can get the pivot table to see this data, that part is going to be more complicated as I have to manipulate the data, but for now its pretty standard.

Answer (score 0):

To correct the error you have commented try this:

```
Set xlptCache.Recordset = pivotRecordSet
```

and than as you have it:

```
Set xlptTable = xlWSheet.PivotTables.Add(xlptCache, Range("D4"), "PT_Report")
```

Comment: I get an Invalid procedure call or argument error when I try that

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have more luck if you post more code.  There's an example that works for me below (based on an existing PivotTable with the same structure data).

There are many many things that can cause "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Two I found are:

- Not opening the recordset
- Not finding the pivot table - e.g. in my code below, I refer to the PivotTable via the ActiveSheet - if I choose a worksheet in Excel that does not have the pivot table on it, I get that error.

Looking at your code there are a couple of things that I'd find questionable, that you might want to review:

- `Set xlptCache = .PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal)` - why are you **adding** a PivotCache ? You need to be updating the PivotCache that belongs to your existing PivotTable.
- `Set .PivotCaches.item(0).Recordset = pivotRecordSet` - I don't like this either, because you're not referencing a specific PivotCache - just the first one on the sheet.

I think you should refer to the `PivotTable` by name, then access the `PivotCache` that belongs to that (See below).

What I suggest you do is fire up your debugger and step through, and make sure you've got the recordset open before you find it, make sure you've actually referred to the proper PivotTable, get a hold of that PivotCache and check that the right objects are being stuck in the right place.

The below code works on my machine (with Excel 2010).

Please note: I've used `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` - to illustrate one of the ways of getting your error.  Your mechanism of using `.Worksheets("Sheet1")` is a better idea for real code.

```
Sub changePivot()


  Dim cnnConn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rstRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim cmdCommand As ADODB.Command

  ' Open the connection.
  Set cnnConn = New ADODB.Connection
  With cnnConn
    .ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .Open "C:\Users\gregh\Documents\Database1.mdb"
  End With

  ' Set the command text.
  Set cmdCommand = New ADODB.Command
  Set cmdCommand.ActiveConnection = cnnConn
  With cmdCommand
   .CommandText = "Select Speed, Pressure, Time From DynoRun2"
   .CommandType = adCmdText
   .Execute
  End With

  ' Open the recordset.
  Set rstRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
  Set rstRecordset.ActiveConnection = cnnConn

  ' if you don't do this, you get the error
  rstRecordset.Open cmdCommand


  Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable
  Dim pc As Excel.PivotCache


  ' Get a hold on the pivot table then the cache

  ' I can trigger the error you mentioned if the ActiveSheet doesn't have the pivot table
  ' Your mechanism of referring to the sheet by name is a much better idea.
  Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

  Set pt = sh.PivotTables("Performance")
  Set pc = pt.PivotCache

  Set pc.Recordset = rstRecordset

  ' The PivotTable doesn't update until you call this 
  pc.Refresh


  ' Close the connections and clean up.
  cnnConn.Close
  Set cmdCommand = Nothing
  Set rstRecordset = Nothing
  Set cnnConn = Nothing

End Sub
```